# Find optimal kerning for space between inline math and text

Tags: kerning

When I write something like

```
$\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra
```

for a C*-algebra, the space between * and - is too large. How do I change this? Are there general criteria on how much such space should be shrinked?

Comment: You can manually insert `\!` in mathmode for a small negative space.

Comment: Thanks! How do I know this is the "right" amount of negative space? (Or do I have to estimate on my own?)

Comment: It's subjective in a case like this... just be consistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an analysis of what happens:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra

\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}-algebra

\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^{\fbox{$\scriptstyle*$}}$}-algebra

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}\kern-.1ex-algebra &
$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.1ex-algebra \\
\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}\kern-.15ex-algebra &
$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.15ex-algebra \\
\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}\kern-.2ex-algebra &
$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.2ex-algebra \\
\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}\kern-.25ex-algebra &
$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.25ex-algebra \\
\fbox{$\mathrm{C}^*$}\kern-.3ex-algebra &
$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.3ex-algebra \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first three rows show the normal typesetting, which I don't find really bad, but it's subjective. The following rows show the same with increasing amount of (negative) kerning; on the left you can see the relation of the hyphen with the bounding box of “C<sup>*</sup>”. When you have decided the right amount, do

```
\newcommand{\csalg}{$\mathrm{C}^*$\kern-.1ex-algebra}
```

and type `\csalg{}` when you want to use the term. Choose the name you prefer, of course. It's probably worthy defining it even if you eventually decide for no kerning.

Comment: Has there ever been attempts to add automatic kerning between math and text? I especially don’t like the looks of `$K$-algebra` and `vector space over~$K$.`. Especially the extra space to the between the `K` and the dot is annoying to look at. The only automatic solution I have found so far is to make a callback in LuaTeX to test for specific combinations.

Comment: @Gaussler TeX doesn't provide anything for this.

Answer (score 6):

This answer presents two other ideas:

### Protruding value of package `microtype`

The TeX engine pdfteX supports a feature "character protrusion". Certain characters (e.g. `-`, `.`, `,`) are allowed to move into the margins. This can improve the visual smoothness of the margins.

Macro `\leftprotrude` grabs the next character and looks at its value for the protrusion into the left margin. `\lpcode<font><character slot>` expands to an integer number, the unit is a per mill of `1em`.

Package `microtype` enables character protrusion and configures some values for the protrusion (they are font-dependent).

### Vertical position of the star

For fun, the example also shows some alternatives:

- Text mode: `\textsuperscript{*}`
- Math mode: star set as limit of an operator (`\mathop`).

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand*{\leftprotrude}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \kern-.001\dimexpr\numexpr(\lpcode\font`#1)em\relax
  \endgroup
  #1%
}

\newcommand*{\CalgA}[1]{%
  \mbox{$\mathrm{C}^{*}$#1-algebra}%
}
\newcommand*{\CalgB}[1]{%
  \mbox{$\mathop{\mathrm{C}}\nolimits^{*}$#1-algebra}%
}
\newcommand*{\CalgC}[1]{%
  \mbox{C\textsuperscript{*}#1-algebra}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}|l@{}|l@{}|l}
  \CalgA{} & \CalgB{} & \CalgC{} & \small(unmodified) \\
  \CalgA{\leftprotrude} & \CalgB{\leftprotrude} & \CalgC{\leftprotrude}
    & \small\verb|\leftprotrude| \\
  \CalgA{\negthinspace} & \CalgB{\negthinspace} & \CalgC{\negthinspace}
    & \small\verb|\negthinspace| \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]